# Thymeleaf select getting selected object

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf form.  with a select field .

```
<form th:object="${contactForm}" th:action="@{/contact}" method="post">
<select th:field="*{cityId}">
        <option th:each="item : ${cityList}"
                th:value="${item.id}" th:text="${item.description}">
</select>
```

When I submit the form, I can get the city id in city field. Is it possible to get the city id and description as a object. if I have a city object in my contactForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Current Code**

I'm just assuming that you are using the following classes based on your html, so lets take them as a starting point.

```
/* This may be called City in your code */
public class Item {
    private Long id;
    private String description;

    // getter/setter/constructor here...
}

public class ContactForm {
    private Long cityId;

    // getter/setter/constructor here...
}
```

**Now what can we do to solve your Problem?**

Spring provides a simple way for adding converters for specific classes, so that you dont have to worry about converting a String to a Year object for example. The same technique can be used for other classes like your Item class as well! Let's look into it:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StringToItemConverter implements Converter<String, Item> {
    @Override
    public Item convert(String source) {
        if(source != null) {
            try {
                Long id = Long.parseLong(source);
                return /* insert your logic for getting an item by it's id here */;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code is automatically executed by Spring whenever it tries to convert a String (from your form input) to an actual java field with the type `Item`. So if we change your ContactForm-class a little bit, spring will automatically asign the Item object for the given id.

```
public class ContactForm {
    /* Note that cityId now has all the information you need (id and description) You should however consider renaming it to city. Don't forget to change the th:field name too! ;) */
    private Item cityId;

    // getter/setter/constructor here...
}
```

**Are you working with Spring Repositories?**

If you are storing your Items in a database you most likely use a CrudRepository for that. In that case the code could look like this. Let's assume that your Repository class is named ItemRepository.

```
@Component
public class StringToItemConverter implements Converter<String, Item> {
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setItemRepository (ItemRepository itemRepository) {
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Item convert(String source) {
        if(source != null) {
            try {
                Long id = Long.parseLong(source);
                return itemRepository.findOne(id);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code would try to convert the String from the form to an actual `Item`-Object by looking the id up in the database. So we either get the `Item` or null if anything goes wrong (for example if there is no item for that id or the String could not be parsed as long).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  so for getting the Item Object I have to hit the Database ?  I was hoping something like a  th:value="${item}" and when posted the Item object to be constructed from it with out hitting DB.   I wanted some thing like in angular JS  ng-model="item" and when I Post ContactForm , spring will construct the ConcatForm and Item object from the @RequestBody automatically.  But I understand this is a limitation when we use server side templating

Comment: you dont have to look it up from the database. how would u normaly look up an item by it's id in your code?

Comment: I would use itemRepository.findOne(id);  if the object is not in cache, then it will hit the DB right ?